net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING 200 (OK) from Ubuntu Apache
I have PHP site running on Ubuntu Apache, that is only accessible on local LAN. I have some PHP code for an image endpoint that returns an image using headers and readfile.
header("Content-type: image/$format");
readfile(ROOTPATH . $src);

For any image larger than a few kilobytes (the majority of images), it doesn't load, and I get this error in Chrome net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING 200 (OK) and this error in Firefox NS_ERROR_NET_PARTIAL_TRANSFER.
If I try opening the endpoint in a new tab, the image loads partially, then stops, at a different point each time. I've tried including a "Content-length" header, but then I get a content length mismatch error. I've tried including a "Connection: keep-alive", but when viewing the request in dev tools it says "keep-alive, close".
This is the first time I've ever seen this error. It must be that the whole file is not being transferred, but why? And how is that different from a request timeout?

Probably something to do with output buffering, and an output handler that applies chunked transfer encoding, but only kicks in above a certain buffer size. Check what output_buffering and output_handler are set to.

Is that server config or headers?

Check the error logs first, maybe php reached the execution time limit (default 30s).

No errors in the log, I set the execution time to 6000 and have the same problem. I should say this is using the CodeIgniter4 framework
